# Error performing 'single click' on view 'view.getId() while running CI using github actions

Tags: android, github, continuous-integration, android-emulator, github-actions

test

```
@Test
    public void testDialogShowsOnEmptyFieldsAll() {
        // Creates a current copy of the activity to test
        ActivityScenario<CreateAccountActivity> scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(CreateAccountActivity.class);

        // Click on the create account button without filling out any fields
        onView(withId(R.id.buttonCreateAccount)).perform(click());

        // Check if the dialog pops up with the correct message
        onView(withText(R.string.createAccountErrorFilledIn))
                .inRoot(isDialog())
                .check(matches(withText(R.string.createAccountErrorFilledIn)));

        scenario.close();
    }
```

yaml

```
name: Android CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - 'feature/*'
      - 'bugfix/*'
      - '*'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '17'

      - name: Ensure script is executable
        run: chmod +x ./gradlew   # Ensure executable permission

      - name: Build with Gradle
        run: ./gradlew assembleDebug

      - name: Run tests with Gradle
        run: ./gradlew test

      - name: Run connected tests
        uses: ReactiveCircus/android-emulator-runner@v2
        with:
          api-level: 33
          target: default
          arch: x86_64
          script: ./gradlew connectedCheck
          enable-hw-keyboard: true
```

This is the test and the yaml file for CI
Everytime I commit all the tests fail to click the same button for some reason.
I am unable to figure out why.
This is my first time using github actions and CI.
Please suggest what could be the problem and potential solutions.

I tried closekeyboard and waiting for activity to load and still the same error arises.
I just want all the tests to run on committing to the branch because they run fine locally.